# s3fs with bacula backups - transport end not connected

Tags: fuse, s3fs, bacula

I'm using s3fs 1.7.3 with fuse 2.9.5 to store backup tapes for the backup system bacula.

What I find is that when bacula finishes backing up one server, I'll get an S3FS error on the directory where I have bacula's virtual backup tapes mounted before it can move onto backing up the next server:

```
[root@ops:/etc/bacula] #df -h /backup/tapes
df: ‘/backup/tapes’: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I mounted the S3FS share using this line in my /etc/fstab and using the 'mount -a' cmmand:

```
s3fs#jf-backup /backup/tapes fuse defaults,noatime,allow_other,uid=133,gid=133,connect_timeout=60,readwrite_timeout=120,use_cache=/cache,default_acl=public-read,multireq_max=5 0 0
```

I'm able to unmount the '/backup/tapes' directory using the 'umount -l /backup/tapes' command, and then remount it through the fstab file with the 'mount -a' command. And when I go into the bacula CLI and mount the directory again I can move onto the next host and back that one up. However, by the time it gets to the host after that, the 'transport connect' error will reoccur.

I really don't want to keep doing this for all 30 hosts that I need to back up ! How can I get s3fs to stay connected so that the nightly backups will happen without intervention?

Thanks

Comment: Can you retest with the latest 1.79?  1.73 is 2.5 years old and the latest code has many bug fixes.

Comment: Sure, Andrew. I'll give that a try and let you know. Thanks!